# What does new Streetpass Quick Plaza do?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass

The latest update added a new feature called **Quick Plaza**.

As far as I know, in this mode each Mii character only gives you their name and location, skipping details like their personal greeting and last game played. Also StreetPass games have their icons moved to the bottom screen instead of living in a separate menu as they do now.

But is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: All the actions are just regular icons that you could just select now.  And there's no animations or whatnot when flipping through them. Hence, _quicker_.

Answer (score 2):

According to [IGN](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://m.ign.com/articles/2016/09/01/new-3ds-streetpass-mini-games-mii-plaza-update-available-today&ved=0ahUKEwjRgKWy1vjOAhWMpY8KHTMqCEYQFggfMAE&usg=AFQjCNHXtBYSCXsICLRu7G6JELtSUrCvTA&sig2=hY2KA6YtRPDoyfRCh5PjrA), Quick Plaza will be introduced for the Mii Plaza, allowing players quicker access to start up Mii Plaza games and sort through greetings from Miis at a more rapid pace.